# How to Properly Align Objects inside Frame in Oracle Reports

Tags: oracle, oraclereports

Im editing some oracle reports.But I cant properly align the objects inside the frame.

See this image:
[image]

I copied the **F_REF1** object, so they are in the same frame.I want to align the **F_REF2** same as F_REF1.But when I did that, F_REF2 is moved to another frame!

See this.

[image]

How to align F_REF2 same as F_REF1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how:

- Switch "confine ON" - it ensures that objects can't be moved out of their frames
- switch "flex OFF", so that moving fields within their frames wouldn't stretch/collapse frames (if possible; if not, you won't even be able to move the field)
- then do the alignment

Also, see whether "snap to grid" is enabled (it should be in the "View" menu). If so, and if fields are placed to "non-matching pixel lines" (I don't know how to express myself), you won't be able to align them nicely. In that case, switch the "snap to grid" OFF. That setting will also let you use "Align" action so that all fields are really nicely aligned (whether horizontally or vertically).

Comment: Disabling **snap to grid** is the answer!!! :) Thank you @Littlefoot!! :)

Comment: Where can I find the "Align" action?

Comment: It is in the "Layout" menu; it is called "Alignment" (sorry for being inaccurate).